# Why won't the excavation site for Mysterious Part B appear?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

I am trying to find [Mysterious Part B](https://xenoblade.fandom.com/wiki/Mysterious_Part_B) to complete [*The Riddle on the Wall*](https://xenoblade.fandom.com/wiki/The_Riddle_on_the_Wall) quest. According to the Wiki, the part should be located in a buried treasure chest in the middle of the Brionac Occupied Zone in the Empire of Mor Ardain. I've gone to the spot [shown in this video](https://youtu.be/daznyn2XdK0?t=563) where it should be buried but there's no excavation site.

Why isn't the excavation site for Mysterious Part B appearing?

[image: Location where Mysterious Part B should be]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The excavation site for Mysterious Part B won't appear until you've found and deciphered [the Mor Ardain Murals](https://xenoblade.fandom.com/wiki/Mor_Ardain_Murals).

[image: Location of Mor Ardain Murals]

To reach the Mor Ardain Murals, fast travel to Empire of Mor Ardain > Alba Cavanich > Nharil Central Plaza. Turn right and climb two sets of stairs to the roof. Walk north until you reach a set of boxes to access the roof. Head back south towards Hardhaigh Palace and use another set of boxes to get over a railing. When you get to the end, jump across to the building straight ahead. Fall down to the left to find the mural next to a ladder.

Once the mural has been deciphered, the excavation site for Mysterious Part B will appear. If you have *Riddle on the Wall* as your active quest, the chest location will be marked on your map.

[image: Visible excavation spot for Part B]